# Navigate to another page and then resume app

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, resume, suspend

I'm developing a UWP app for both mobile and PCs.
I need to ask for a passcode every time the app start, also when resumed after suspension.
When the app is resumed I navigate to a pin check page, then, if the passcode is correct I navigate to the page which was shown before suspending.
The problem is that I have a page with a textbox and other control, how can I resume the text in TextBox?
When I resume the app without using pin page, I have no problem because the content of the page is totally resumed.
Thanks

Comment: You need to save the textbox text in Temporary Application Settings. Since you are already saving the application state / Navigated page during OnSuspending ( If you are not doing it now, look for OnSuspending in App.xaml.cs), when your app is activated, if there is value in setting, instead of navigating to your main page, you go to Login Page and Use this text saved in application settings to fill your textbox. Taking few steps further, Since you have the text, you can fire the login event and allow them to login if required. Let me know if you need more clarification. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I have a page with a textbox and other control, how can I resume the text in TextBox?

You can use [UIElement.CacheMode property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.cachemode.aspx) and [Frame.CacheSize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.cachesize.aspx) to cache the content of the page. You can refer to my another case [UWP page state manage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944277/uwp-page-state-manage/35980891#35980891).

Or if you're using some templates for example template 10 to develop your app, you can use its own cache method, you can refer to [Docs | Navigation Cache](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Docs-%7C-Navigation-Cache).