# How to save selected index of a combobox in UWP and display it back when the user reloads the page?

Tags: c#, combobox, uwp, selectedindex

I have a `ComboBox` control in my UWP application and I need to save the selected index of it when the user is selecting an option! Then, I need to save this index in local settings and when the user is coming back on this page, I want the `ComboBox` to have this saved index as the selected index. I need this functionality in my settings page! Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```
private void fuelTypeSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

    try
    {
        if(localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("selectedIndex"))
        {
            int index = (int)localSettings.Values["selectedIndex"];
            fuelTypeSelector.SelectedIndex = index;

            //update the saved index

            if(fuelTypeSelector.SelectedIndex!=index)
            {
                localSettings.Values["selectedIndex"] =
                    fuelTypeSelector.SelectedIndex;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // index does not exist
            localSettings.Values.Add("selectedIndex",
                fuelTypeSelector.SelectedIndex);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the selected item of [ComboBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you can handle its [SelectionChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx), just for example here:

```
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 4</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 5</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

code behind:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //you can get the selected item like this:
    var combo = sender as ComboBox;
    var selecteditem = combo.SelectedItem;

    //or, since ComboBox DOESN'T support multiple selection, you can get the item like:
    var selecteditems = e.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Or if you just need the index of this item, you can use the first method and change the code like this: `var selectedindex = combo.SelectedIndex;`. And of course we can also add items to the Collection of `ComboBox` through [data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/data-binding/index).

By saving the selected item, I personal think it's better to save your local settings when your app is at the suspending stage, and read the settings data at the launched stage. To check the lifecycle of UWP app, the official document [Launching, resuming, and background tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/launch-resume/index) will help you. This means you will have to save your page state during the run time of your app, to do this, you can cache your Setting page, for more information about page state, you can refer to my answer in [UWP page state manage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944277/uwp-page-state-manage/35980891#35980891).

For saving and retrieving settings part, here is the official documentation: [Store and retrieve settings and other app data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data), there are some sample code in this doc.

Finally since you're new to UWP app development, you can refer to [How-to articles for UWP apps on Windows 10](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop) to get started. And there are a lot of [official UWP samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) on GitHub which may also help.

Comment: I am trying to save the selectedIndex so when the user come back to this page, I want te comboBox to have as a selectedIndex the selectedIndex which was selected before by him. How can I achieve that? If I save the selectedIndex in every selection_changed event and try to set it as a default in the comboBox, the comboBox takes always the same index! What I'm doing wrong? Is my logic correct?

Comment: @TasosTheodosiou, you can compare the selected Item with the saved one to decide if this is a new setting, if you don't compare them, when you set the last settings once the page is open, the  `selection_changed` event will raise only one time, why you think the comboBox takes always the same index? This event will only fire when the last item is different with the new one or the last selected item is null. As I said, during the runtime, you can cache the page's content.

Comment: @TasosTheodosiou, I understand that you're new to UWP, so I took some time to wrote a [settings demo](https://github.com/GraceFeng/SettingPageDemo), you may take a look at it.

Comment: Do you want save the state of the page and reload all the controls' states when user come back to the page?