# UWP - How to save frame backstack and current page?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Hi I have this hierarchy

App (RootFrame)

- Login Page
- Main Shell (InnerFrame)

  - List Page with entities 1
  - List Page with entities 2
- Detail Page for entity 1 (InnerFrame2)

  - subpage 1-1
  - subpage 1-2
- Detail Page for entity 2 (InnerFrame3)

  - subpage 2-1
  - subpage 2-1

And I want to handle Back button correctly. Navigating between pages in inner frames is ok, but when I go for example from "List Page with entities 2" to "Detail page for entity 2" and then back, MainShell i recreated and forgets the InnerFrames BackStack and opened Page(should be "List Page with entities 2")

Is there any elegant way to handle this? for example save InnerFrames history and current page when navigatedFrom at MainShell happens?

Comment: Did you mean you have three frames in one same page? Could you please provide a [mcve] if conveniently?If not, at least provide a screenshot please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed. There are SetNavigationState(string) and GetNavigationState() methods on Frame object. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Prism Framework](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism), here is a lifecycle managing [example](http://blog.qmatteoq.com/prism-and-universal-windows-app-managing-the-applications-lifecycle/).

In a nutshell Prism provides `SessionStateService` to manage view restoring when `OnAppSuspended` and `OnAppResumed` events invoked.

Also Prism `NavigationService` passes `NavigatedToEventArgs e, NavigatedFromEventArgs e, Dictionary<string, object> viewModelState` parameters and your page behaviour can be overrided in `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatedFrom` using this parameters.

Comment: I know how to save state in ViewModel but I probably need to save (and reload) state of Frame and I dont know how to do it (basically how to save and restore Frame.BackStack and Frame.Content)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944277/uwp-page-state-manage) will help